# How can I fix an integer checking function?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple quiz for a project, but I can't get an integer checker to work.

I'm trying to make it so it prints an error for floats and strings, then lets you enter another thing for the same question. My previous one gave a python error and ended the program when entering a float / string.

```
def int_checker(question):
    user = input(question)

    passcheck = False
    while passcheck is False:
        if isinstance(user, int) is True:
            passcheck = True
            return passcheck
    
    
        elif isinstance(user, int) is True:
            print()
            print("Whole numbers only, please.")
            passcheck = False
            return passcheck
    
        else:
            print()
            print("Numbers only, please.")
            passcheck = False
            return passcheck
    return user
```

When I type anything, it gives me the final print statement, then lets me type another input in.

So, is there anyway I can make it say the correct message for each input type, and have it so if I type in an integer, it lets the code use that input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side-note: [Testing `if expression is True:` is almost always bad](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). There are *incredibly* rare cases where being actually `True`, as opposed to merely being "truthy" is important, but 99.99% of the time (if not more) you should just be doing `if expression:`. `isinstance` checks are definitely one of those times (they already return `True` or `False`, and checking if they're actually `True` is pointless overhead).

Comment: `input` **always** returns a string so checking if it's an int is useless...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Python 3, `user` variable will always be a `string` object, because `input` function in Python 3 always returns string, so using `isinstance` function won't help. That's why interpreter won't ever execute `if` and `elif` block. If you need to check if user input is a number, then you should implement something like this:

```
def isValidInt(stringInput):
    try:
        int(stringInput)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

and use `isValidInt(user)` instead of `isinstance(user, int)`.

Few things I want to point out:

1. I noticed that condition in both `if` and `elif` are same. Probably, you wanted to do something else and wrote it by mistake.
2. Having `while` loop in your function won't make any difference. If you drop it, it will work same.

---

Refer this implementation if you face any problems:

```
def intChecker(question):
    while True:
        userInput = input(question)

        if isValidInt(userInput):
            return int(userInput)

        if isValidFloat(userInput):                 # Refer isValidInt for implementation of isValidFloat
            print("Whole numbers only, please.")
        else:
            print("Numbers only, please.")
```

Comment: The `while` would help if they moved `user = input(question)` into the body of the `while`, as the first line.

Comment: Thanks, will test these out!

Comment: I tried using Aniket's code, but it kept repeating the error message I had later in the code constantly. Should I send a link to my file?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, that makes sense. I included it in my updated answer.

Comment: @AWildPotato Check my updated answer. I added additional code for you to refer. You can show me your code if you still face problems.